# How to get the list of uncommon element from two list using java?

Tags: java

I need to get the list of uncommon element while comparing two lists .
ex:-

```
List<String> readAllName = {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"};
List<String> selectedName = {"bbb","ccc"};
```

here i want uncommon elements from readAllName list ("aaa","ccc","ddd") in another list.
Without Using remove()and removeAll().

Comment: how about ccc? should it be in the final list too?

Comment: How is ccc uncommon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the expected output is `aaa, ccc, eee, fff, xxx` (all the not-common items), you can use [`List#removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), but you need to use it twice to get both the items in name but not in name2 AND the items in name2 and not in name:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<> (name);
list.removeAll(name2); //list contains items only in name

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<> (name2);
list2.removeAll(name); //list2 contains items only in name2

list2.addAll(list); //list2 now contains all the not-common items
```

---

As per your edit, you can't use `remove` or `removeAll` - in that case you can simply run two loops:

```
List<String> uncommon = new ArrayList<> ();
for (String s : name) {
    if (!name2.contains(s)) uncommon.add(s);
}
for (String s : name2) {
    if (!name.contains(s)) uncommon.add(s);
}
```

Comment: Without using remove() and removeAll()

Comment: @Arun Why not? If there are any restrictions you need to make them clear in your question.

Comment: bcz i tried it doesn't work at @postconstruct method  but it work junit test  correctly .i don't knw y???

Comment: @Arun I don't understandy your comment (it would help if you wrote in plain English) - the 2 methods I proposed in my answer do what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Guava libraries to do this. The [Sets](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class has a [difference](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) method

You would have to run it twice I think to get all the differences from both sides.