# How to find elements that make the difference between the two lists

Tags: java

I need to make a generic method that receives two lists and returns a list that contains the elements that make the difference between the two lists.

This is what I tried:

These are my lists:

```
 List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("Real Madrid");
    list1.add("Barcelona");
    list1.add("Everton");
    list1.add("Fulham");
    list1.add("Sunderland");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add("Real Madrid");
    list2.add("Barcelona");
    list2.add("Everton");
    list2.add("Fulham");
    list2.add("Partizan");
```

The output I'm getting is:

> [Sunderland]

However, the output I require is:

> [Partizan, Sunderland]

Here is my code for computing the difference between the two lists:

```
public static <T> void difference(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    Set<T> uniqueElementsInList1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
    Set<T> uniqueElementsInList2 = new HashSet<>(list2);
    uniqueElementsInList2.removeAll(uniqueElementsInList1);
    System.out.println(uniqueElementsInList2);
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Please add to your question the output of what you've tried and how it differs from your desired output. See [mre] for more info on that.

Answer (score 3):

A few hints:

```
public static <T> void difference(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
```

That method signature says void. Your text says: should return a list. So why not:

```
public static <T> List<T> difference(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
```

Then:

```
Set<String> ad = new HashSet<String>((Collection<? extends String>) list1);
```

You have that generic T, there is no need to think about Strings:

```
Set<T> uniqueElementsInList1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
```

then you are almost there:

```
uniqueElementsInList1.removeAll(new HashSet<>(list2));
return new ArrayList<>(uniqueElements);
```

Comment: @Johnez Well, then read [mcve] and enhance your question. We cant help you unless you tell us exactly what bothers you. As said: a lot of stuff in your code simply doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Johnez In which way? You are **not** telling us what your problem is. I gave you plenty of instructions how to get to a working solution, so sorry: right now I have **no** clue what you A) expect from us B) what your actual problem is.

Comment: Like I said, my problem is I can't find the elements that make the difference between my two strings. Also, I gave an example of how I tried to solve my problem. What else do you expect?

Comment: Program print me just Sunderland, he need to print and Partizan too. Thank you btw.

Comment: @Johnez Update the question with those expected outputs please.

Comment: I think you need something like `Set<T> uniqueElementsInList2 = new HashSet<>(list2); uniqueElementsInList2.removeAll(new HashSet<>(list1));` and finally return a new array list where you added both `uniqueElementsInList1` and `uniqueElementsInList2`.

Comment: I did it. For example if I had one array `1,2,3,4,5` and second array `1,2,6,7,8,9` program need to print `1,2` because that is different in that two list.

Comment: I would not think that is considered the difference between the two lists. More like what the two lists have in common.

Comment: I would think the difference in the lists would print out `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

Comment: Yeah program need to print me `3,4,5,6,7,8,9` i was confused.

Comment: @Johnez Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645319/how-to-get-the-list-of-uncommon-element-from-two-list-using-java) what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, program again just print me `Sunderland` or `Partizan`. Idk how to make so program print me both

Comment: @Johnez [It seems to do what you request](https://tio.run/##hZIxb8IwEIX3/IoTUyKVILxCkajUTlSqClvV4ZoYMHXOkeMEUcRvT52YAiUJZLF87/I9v7M3WGB/E3@XpUhSpQ1sbCHMjZDhVGvczURmRl5Dc2Uvzb@kiCCSmGXwioJg73lgv6OQGTR2KZSIIalkf260oBV8fALqVRbs6@7qq4hjp05A2s0QHoH4Fk7HGE/8YHTqr1tCjGO/985RWvdYi7jX3vGEOuJSEXbozwXXRlGH@pLLNSYd4jynmGuJVHt3x2H347C7cdidOOxmHHYrzlF8Q23ED9K/MPNdZngSqtyEqU1kJPmxWC655hRxvx7Gg4MER@qh7RmMFxM3F7te/P9XEpTmZuZgjRoL4OqtLNxcm2MF/0y6ChlqnqiCT6X0L8gjGAxqVKTI2FeagbBxM1Akd/YEQJhwr9Wc3XRnjRG32A9P9uyWP/Oat1Vxqs0FgdT2TEEpway5LZp@pJJEkQOfUZqbXJMj/l3cwSvLXw).

Comment: @Ivar Yeah, thats it. Thank you. I just now need to see how it excatly works. :0